# Is Vegemite kosher?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

Is Vegemite kosher? What hechsher?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As of 2010, Australian Vegemite is now
>   Kosher. However, bottles must be
>   inspected before purchase for the "K"
>   symbol above the barcode since Kosher
>   Vegemite prior to 2010 was only
>   produced in batches

[Vegemite (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegemite#Kosher_and_Halal)

[Vegemite.com](http://www.vegemite.com.au/vegemite/page?siteid=vegemite-prd&locale=auen1&PagecRef=757)

[Spreads (Kashrut Authority)](http://www.ka.org.au/index.php/component/option,com_kosherdb/Itemid,102/catid,90/)

[Auckland Hebrew Congregation](http://www.kosher.co.nz/files/kkvisitorguide.pdf)

> se-or שְׂאוֹר. The second of two
>   categories of foods (see chometz,
>   above) which are forbidden during
>   Pesach. Se-or includes Marmite™ and
>   Vegemite™.

[Other glossaries of Kosher, Jewish, Passover and Food terms](http://www.hechshers.info/glossary/index.htm)

Comment: It's kosher, but eating it might violate the principle of "lo teshaktzu"....   (just kidding)  :o)

Comment: -1: now includes outdated information. Please see ["Vegemite" on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegemite#Kosher_and_Halal) for up-to-date information. Dear Gershon, I wonder if you could copy and paste in the more-current information included in the right-hand side of  [suggested edit 6068](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/6068)?

Comment: @unforgettableid: You can always edit yourself if the information is outdated.